# Invalid JSON response Laravel Datatable

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I use laravel 5.2 and Yajra Datatable to implement tables with ajax. I followed this tutorial : https://datatables.yajrabox.com/ but at the end I have "Invalid JSON response" and I don't know why.

My controller :

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{

    return view("contacts.list");
}

public function data()
{
    $contacts = Contact::select(array(
             'NOM', 'PRENOM'
        ));

        return(Datatables::of($contacts)->make(true));
}
}
```

My view :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="users">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>NOM</th>
          <th>PRENOM</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
 </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#users').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "{{ route('contacts.data') }}",
      "columns": [
        {data: 'NOM', name: 'NOM'},
        {data: 'PRENOM', name: 'PRENOM'}
      ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

My routes :

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
Route::get('contacts/data', ['as' => 'contacts.data', 'uses' => 'ContactController@data']);
```

The result of

```
dd(Datatables::of($contacts)->make(true))
```

in my controller when I do it in index() is:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it? I get this error: DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: check the response in network tab may it contain `<?php` in first data

Answer (score 2):

I guess it should be:

```
return(Datatables::of($contacts->get())->make(true));
```

Comment: Yes It's seems logical, but I have the same result with get()

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in Yajra DataTables version  10. The DataTables were working well on the localhost but had issues on the server. I was using HTML Builder.
In the DataTable class, I had the following code:

```
public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('casinoproviders-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    //->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->selectStyleSingle()
                    ->buttons([
                        // Button::make('excel'),
                        // Button::make('csv'),
                        // Button::make('pdf'),
                    ]);
    }
```

I was missing `->postAjax()` method. It started working once I added the method on the HTML builder. The final code that got it working is:

```
public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('casinoproviders-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->postAjax([
                        'data' => 'function(d) {
                            d._token = "' . csrf_token() . '";
                        }',
                    ])//I added this ->postAjax() method
                    //->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->selectStyleSingle()
                    ->buttons([
                        // Button::make('excel'),
                        // Button::make('csv'),
                        // Button::make('pdf'),
                    ]);
    }
```